# Changing flavors on Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, upgrade

Which is the easiest way to change flavors in ubuntu?? Thanks I'm a newbie just trying new things.I haven't tested any out right now running ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

-Installing the Flavour as your new OS.

-Using the terminal to install the flavour's desktop

I will give you the instructions for this last option.
Open the terminal and install the flavour's desktop you want with this command (e.g. Budgie):

```
 sudo apt install ubuntu-budgie-desktop
```

Please bear in mind that this last option will only give you the **graphical interface** of the flavour, if you want to **use** the flavour as your main OS, you need to install it the same way you installed Ubuntu.